# Shuffle an array of objects and maintain Grouping in Java

Tags: java, collections, grouping, shuffle

I need to Shuffle an array of albums and songs.

For Example, given a randomized array of songs:

```
[AlbumB:Song3, AlbumA:Song2, AlbumB:Song1, AlbumA:Song1, AlbumB:Song2, AlbumC:Song1]
```

The output of the shuffle method might be:

```
[AlbumB:Song1, AlbumB:Song2, AlbumB:Song3, AlbumC:Song1, AlbumA:Song1, AlbumA:Song2]
```

Notice that the songs of each album are grouped together.
Calling the shuffle method again might give the following result:

```
[AlbumC:Song1, AlbumA:Song1, AlbumA:Song2, AlbumB:Song1, AlbumB:Song2, AlbumB:Song3].
```

My program follows,
I could not get the grouping to work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Music {

    public final String album;
    public final String song;

    public Music(String album, String song) {
        this.album = album;
        this.song = song;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Music music1 = new Music("AlbumB","Song3");
        Music music2 = new Music("AlbumA","Song2");
        Music music3 = new Music("AlbumB","Song1");
        Music music4 = new Music("AlbumA","Song1");
        Music music5 = new Music("AlbumB","Song2");
        Music music6 = new Music("AlbumC","Song1");

        Music[] musicArr = new Music[]{
                new Music("AlbumB","Song3"),new Music("AlbumA","Song2"),new Music("AlbumB","Song1"),
                new Music("AlbumA","Song1"),new Music("AlbumB","Song2"),new Music("AlbumC","Song1")
        };
        System.out.println("Before Shuffle ");

        for (Music music : musicArr) {
            System.out.println(music.album + " " + music.song);

        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(musicArr));
        System.out.println("After Shuffle ");

        for (Music music : musicArr) {
            System.out.println(music.album + " " + music.song);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not seeing the 2-dimensional array. Just an array of Music objects.

Comment: I need to Shuffle and maintain grouping not sort.

Comment: That is a single dimensional array, perhaps your desired goal would be easier if you had an array of albums `Album(String name, String... songs)` and then you could shuffle albums in your array while maintaining the order of songs.

Comment: Reginol - I tried to achieve it with objects but as you see in the question,  the requirement was to shuffle a two dimensional array of albums and songs  and maintain the grouping of albums irrespective of the number of times shuffle is perfomed.

Comment: Danny - Can you help me on how to do that or provide pointers?

Answer (score 1):

***Some Notes***

1. Nothing about this is a 2-dimensional array.
2. You are not shuffling songs, you are shuffling albums.
3. Learn to use objects.
4. Stop depending on arrays and use Collections (perhaps a List).
5. It is good to clearly state "I need help with my homework".
6. [Map API Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
7. [LinkedList API Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
8. [Comparable API Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

***Steps for the solution***

1. Build a `List` of songs for each album.
   Use a `Map<String, List<Music>>` for this.
   The album name is the map key (the String part).
2. For each Music in the input List,
   get the correct `List<Music>` from the `Map` and add the `Music` to the `List`.
3. Special handling required for the first time an album is found in the input List.
4. Get the list of keys from the `Map`.
5. Shuffle the list of keys.
6. For each element in the shuffled key list, get the list of Music objects and append them to a play list.
7. Print the play list.
8. Consider implementing `Comparable` on the `Music` object to sort the list of songs in an album or shuffle each of the Music object lists before adding them to the play list.